# Multiple hyperlinks in one cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have got a problem connected with hyperlinks in Excel. I would like to have few hyperlinks in one cell. Is it possible? I read something about rectangles in which I should put each link, but I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: how far you done? what help you need? your requirement is not clear

Comment: I want to put two Rectangle shapes into one cell and link some page to each of them.

Comment: You can put a link on a shape of rectangle as you are saying. One shape can only have one link. You can have 2 such shapes and locate them in one cell. This way it might look like you have 2 links in one cell, but the real thing would be that you have one link on each of the shape and no actual link on a cell.

Comment: And that would suit me. But I dont know how to do this with apache-poi. I can do it manually in Excel by clicking on shape etc. But how to make it in java?

Answer (score 4):

Putting aside POI, I looked to see if it is actually possible to have multiple hyperlinks in a cell in Excel itself:

http://excel.tips.net/T002805_Putting_More_than_One_Hyperlink_in_a_Cell.html

> The short answer is that this cannot be done. Excel only allows you to enter hyperlinks on a cell-by-cell basis. Even if you add the hyperlinks to adjacent cells, and then merge the cells into one, only the first hyperlink is maintained by Excel.

As such, POI can't do this either.